# Jmockit TestNG/JUnit NullPointerException with Seam

Tags: seam, jmockit

I had been using jmock with seam all these days, but its not sufficient to mock final/static/enums. So I tried working with JMockit. However everytime I run, I get NPE. Can't even debug, below is sample code

```
public class TestJmockit extends SeamTest {

@Mocked Dependency dependencyInCodeToTest;
CodeToTest bean = new CodeToTest();

@Test
 public void testSaveSectionChangesJMockit() throws Exception {
    new AbstractSeamTest.ComponentTest() {
        @Override
        protected void testComponents() throws Exception {

                new NonStrictExpectations()
                {
                  {
                    dependencyInCodeToTest.getLabel(); result = "Normal";
                  }
                };

                bean.execute();
        }
    }.run();
}

}
```

Actual Code..

```
package com.abc.action.account.information;

import com.abc.vo.account.ExternalAccountStatus;
import com.abc.vo.account.information.ExternalAccountStatusClosedInfo;
import com.abc.vo.account.information.ExternalAccountStatusInfo;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;
import org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest;
import org.jboss.seam.mock.SeamTest;
import org.junit.Test;


public class ConsumerAccountInformationActionTestJmockit extends SeamTest {

    @Mocked ExternalAccountStatus mockExternalAccountStatus;
    @Mocked ExternalAccountStatusInfo mockExternalAccountStatusInfo;

//    ConsumerAccountInformationAction bean = new ConsumerAccountInformationAction();


@Test
 public void testSaveSectionChangesJMockit() throws Exception {
    new AbstractSeamTest.ComponentTest() {
        @Override
        protected void testComponents() throws Exception {

                new NonStrictExpectations()
                {
                  {
                    mockExternalAccountStatus.getLabel(); result = "Normal";
                    mockExternalAccountStatusInfo.getClosedInfo(); result = new ExternalAccountStatusClosedInfo();
                  }
                };

//                bean.saveSectionChanges();
        }
    }.run();
}

}
```

If I put a breakpoint at class declaratiom (Public Class Consumer..), stepping over to next line causes NPE. If I take out the commented lines in the code, it fails at the first uncommented line.

I am using Java 1.6 and IntelliJ IDE. Wonder if it has to do with IDE configuration.

With TestNG I dont even get the stack trace, with JUnit I see the below..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.ServletApplicationMap.get(ServletApplicationMap.java:54)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.BasicContext.get(BasicContext.java:49)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.BasicContext.get(BasicContext.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Init.instance(Init.java:117)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.BusinessProcessContext.<init>(BusinessProcessContext.java:47)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.TestLifecycle.beginTest(TestLifecycle.java:35)
    at org.jboss.seam.mock.AbstractSeamTest$ComponentTest.run(AbstractSeamTest.java:159)
    at com.billmelater.csa.action.account.information.ConsumerAccountInformationActionTestJmockit.testSaveSectionChangesJMockit(ConsumerAccountInformationActionTestJmockit.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:199)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace you get? and possibly the code you are trying to test? (And your real test code)

Comment: And also which line exactly is NPE'ing.

Comment: Added the complete test code.. Unit Code (code am trying to test) is too long and am sure doesnt have a problem. I am able to test it with just Jmock.

Answer (score 0):

General Objection:  mocking is there to isolate you from external code, 
especially from those coming from your server wendor ( like AbstractSeamtest )  - so 
you do not have to initialize  them or have server runing or whatever.

Treat mocked test as saved debug session.   In your case you like to assure (I'm guessing),  that  method

```
bean.saveSectionChanges();
```

interacts correctly with seam infrastructure, or other collaborators. This is easily achieved by something like:

```
public static testProperInteraction(@Mocked final Collaborator collaborator) {
    new Expectations() {
        {
            collaborator.doThis(with some parameters);
            returns(something you like);
        }
    };

   Bean bean = new Bean(collaborator);

  assertSomething(bean.saveSessionChanges());

   // nothing else shall be called
    new FullVerifications() {
        {
        }
    };
}
```